# Can I use "Week start" as alternative of "Week starts on"

Tags: grammaticality

I want to use "Week start" for the same purpose as in Google Calendar settings:

[image: Week starts on]

It sounds clear for English-speaking people? Or it would be better to use "Week starts on"?

Comment: But........Why?

Comment: @NVZ, I want to get a short phrase without verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *possibly* could, but I'd recommend **First Day of Week**. This seems to be the norm among programs.

Here is an example from the calendar settings in Microsoft Outlook:

[image: Microsoft Outlook Calendar Settings]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did ... I also found the use of such variant: **Week start day**.